# signtool fails to sign installer when i am running from atlassian Bamboo

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing, bamboo, code-signing-certificate, signtool

I am trying to automate code signing from Bamboo for an internal security measure.

Signing command:

```
signtool.exe sign /v /debug /f "\\hostname\Cert$\Cerfile.pfx" /p "password" /d "Company name" /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" "c:\test\installer.msi"
```

I am using an internally generated certificate from our IT department, which is in .pfx form.

Verification:

```
signtool verify /pa "c:\test\installer.msi"
```

Both commands work perfectly fine if I run from the local machine (same user as bamboo service user) command window. It fails when I run this from Atlassian Bamboo as a script task.

It stops at "Done Adding Additional Store". No errors or success message comes after this.

A successful signing prints below at the end, this comes when I am running from localhost.

```
.........
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: c:\test\installer.msi

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

This is what I see if I run the same command from Bamboo.

```
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    The following certificates were considered:
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued to: RnD Software Engineering
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued by: <....>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Expires:   <...........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        SHA1 hash: <...........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued to: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued by: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Expires:   <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        SHA1 hash: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued to: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued by: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Expires:   <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        SHA1 hash: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    After EKU filter, 3 certs were left.
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    After expiry filter, 3 certs were left.
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    The following certificate was selected:
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued to: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued by: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Expires:   <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        SHA1 hash: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    The following additional certificates will be attached:
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued to: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Issued by: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        Expires:   <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07        SHA1 hash: <........>
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    Done Adding Additional Store
```

Verification log

```
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    File: c:\abc\installer.msi
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    Index  Algorithm  Timestamp    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:07    ========================================
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:08    
build   20-Jan-2017 08:05:08    Number of errors: 1
error   20-Jan-2017 08:05:08    SignTool Error: No signature found.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem using different timestamp server. Below command worked from Bamboo inline script task.

```
signtool.exe sign /v /debug /f "\\hostname\Cert$\Cerfile.pfx" /p "password" /d "Company name" /tr "http://sha1timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha1/timestamp" "c:\test\installer.msi"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Interesting that */tr* worked for you when it did not for me. I had to use */t* instead, otherwise timestamping failed in my Bamboo job with "this function is not supported" or something like that.